# How to organize a list returned by a sql query in angular.js

Tags: php, html, mysql, angularjs

I apologize if this isn't the best code anyone has ever seen. I'm somewhat new to angular.js.

My problem is this: when the data is returned from my query it simply displays as a block of text. In search.php, inserting echo statements simple displays the output of the echo statement instead of generating the code. I can't seem to force the output to behave.

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

$db = mysql_connect("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx") or die ("Error connecting to     database.");
mysql_select_db("Awards_New", $db) or die ("Couldn't select the database.");

$results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Awards WHERE AwardName LIKE "%'. $objData->data .'%"');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
echo $row['AwardName'] . " ";
}

mysql_close($db);
```

The bit of html...

```
<div ng-controller="SearchCtrl">
    <form class="well form-search">
      <label>Search:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="keywords" class="input-medium search-query" placeholder="Keywords...">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
      <p class="help-block">Single words only: eg; AFS, University, Geology</p>      
    </form>
    <div ng-model="result">

            {{result}}

    </div>

</div>
```

and the js... (this is my weakest link)

```
function SearchCtrl($scope, $http) {
$scope.url = 'search.php';
$scope.search = function() {
    $http.post($scope.url, { "data" : $scope.keywords}).
    success(function(data, status) {
        $scope.status = status;
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.result = data;
    })
    .
    error(function(data, status) {
        $scope.data = data || "Fail.";
        $scope.status = status;         
    });
};
}
```

What I am trying to do is organize the data in to distinct rows upon retrieval. However, nothing I can do seems to work. At this point, I'm not sure where I should look next for direction to resources and help.

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize the `ng-repeat` function to iterate through each row of your query results. In this example I used a `<table>` structure and placed an `ng-repeat` function inside a `<tr>` element, but you can use `ng-repeat` on other element types, like `<div>` or `<span>`, if you prefer.

```
<body id="ng-app" ng-app="sotest">
<div ng-controller="searchCtrl">
    <form class="well form-search">
      <label>Search:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="keywords" class="input-medium search-query"     placeholder="Keywords...">
      <button type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="search()">Search</button>
      <p class="help-block">Single words only: eg; AFS, University, Geology</p>      
    </form>

    <table>
        <tr> <!-- this is the column header row -->
           <th>AwardName</th>
           <th>SomeColumnName</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="row in result"> <!-- this tr will generate for each row in the query result-->
           <td>{{row.AwardName}}</td>
           <td>{{row.SomeColumnName}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Additionally, I suggest using the angularJS DeferredAPI and Promises to get your async data. You will need to inject $q into your controller to do so. Note I have restructured your JS code slightly, separating the database call into a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="Text/javascript" >
var app = angular.module('sotest', []);

app.controller('searchCtrl',['$scope','$http','$q', function SearchCtrl($scope, $http, $q) {

    $scope.search = function(){
        $scope.result = $scope.fetchData();        
    }

    $scope.fetchData= function() {
      $scope.url = 'index.php';
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http.post($scope.url).
      success(function(data, status) {
          deferred.resolve(data) 
      })
      .
      error(function(data, status) {    
          deferred.reject('An unexpected error has occurred');
      });
      return deferred.promise; //return the data
  };

  }]);
</script>
```

I modified your PHP to return a JSON-encoded array, and added the $db connection to your mysql_query line:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");

$objData = json_decode($data);

$db = mysql_connect("xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx") or die ("Error connecting to     database.");
mysql_select_db("Awards_New", $db) or die ("Couldn't select the database.");

$results = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM Awards WHERE AwardName LIKE "%'. $objData->data .'%"', $db);

$array_result = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){    
  $array_result[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($array_result);

mysql_close($db);
```

You can read more on $q and deferred promises here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Comment: Thanks for restructuring the js. It's still not working as intended though. I think the problem lies in the php; specifically, there is no mechanism in place for returning a single record from the query, just the entire result. What I think I need to do is find a way to iterate through the query with each record treated as a separate result, while making sure the entire table is searched. Ugh. I'm beginning to think I should just do this all in php and skip the angular.js altogether.

Comment: @user2220638 Ok I got it working, and updated my answer. The ng-repeat will now dump the entire results of the query onto the page.  You can limit the results returned in the PHP by manipulating that $array_result[] array object. Finally, if you are still getting nothing, then I suggest watching the firebug console to make sure the POST to your PHP file actually has RESPONSE data.

Comment: I watched the console. The query runs correctly with the keywords and the php file returns the record as a json string. From there, things go wonky. Nothing displays in the html and, honestly, given my lack of experience with angular, I couldn't even begin to tell you why. I'll keep plugging away at it and post here whatever progress I can make.